# Can you get the path markup syntax for a CombinedGeometry or a GeometryGroup object?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

When dealing with a `PathGeometry` object, if you call `ToString()` you get back the 'path markup syntax' representing the paths.  However, the same is not true for `GeometryGroup` and `CombinedGeometry`.

Consider the following code:

```
var hBar  = Geometry.Parse("F1M10,20L40,20L40,30L10,30z");
var vBar  = Geometry.Parse("F1M20,10L30,10L30,40L20,40z");
var cross = Geometry.Parse("F1M20,10L20,10L30,10L30,20L40,20L40,30L30,30L30,40L20,40L20,30L10,30L10,20L20,20z");

var combined = new GeometryGroup(){ FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero };
    combined.Children.Add(hBar);
    combined.Children.Add(vBar);

var union = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, HBar.Geometry, VBar.Geometry);

Console.WriteLine($"hBar     : {hBar}");
Console.WriteLine($"vBar     : {vBar}");
Console.WriteLine($"cross    : {cross}");
Console.WriteLine($"combined : {combined}");
Console.WriteLine($"union    : {union}");
```

Here are the images:
[image]

The output from the code is as follows:

```
hBar     : F1M10,20L40,20 40,30 10,30z
vBar     : F1M20,10L30,10 30,40 20,40z
cross    : F1M20,10L20,10 30,10 30,20 40,20 40,30 30,30 30,40 20,40 20,30 10,30 10,20 20,20z
combined : System.Windows.Media.GeometryGroup
union    : System.Windows.Media.CombinedGeometry
```

What I'm hoping is to get the resulting path markup syntax for the `CombinedGeometry` and `GeometryGroup` objects.  For instance, specifically in the case of 'union', I'm hoping to get back something similar to the `cross` entry.

(* Note: I don't care about the order of the vertices or the drawing direction as long as it shows as an identical shape/path.)

Here's the Microsoft page all about [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). This is the format I'm trying to get.

So is this possible?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, It wasn't snide at all!  I literally felt bad because you clearly put a lot of effort into your answer but it wasn't quite what I had asked.  I'd actually recommend you putting it back because it will help others! BUT... turns out it wasn't a single line anyway as that flattens out curved geometry.  Unfortunately my demo code was all polygons so it worked fine, but that's not quite the solution either.  :/

Comment: The only way to get the exact markup is to have the framework emit the XAML, using `XamlWriter`. Which is why, given you wrote _"to get the resulting path markup syntax"_ in your question, I posted the answer I did. I obviously have no idea who downvoted it, but that's all the attention it got, and a clear comment from you saying it didn't answer your question. So, no need to undelete it nor any reason for me to want to.

Comment: Don't you want the markup *after* the transformation?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I was (perhaps incorrectly) going under the assumption that the path markup syntax has nothing to do with XAML per se.  It's just a simple serialization format for geometries.  That said, if the XAMLWriter gives that back out, then I would argue that *is* the correct answer.  I'm currently updating my own demo code to add in arc lines (instead of just straight line segments) to see if that makes any difference. Again, if the XAML version works, then I'll be more than happy to accept it.  I just have to test all scenarios first.

Comment: The `XamlWriter` is just going to emit your exact object graph. It won't produce a geometry stream that is the flattened version of the original geometries. It _will_ emit XAML that will reproduce _exactly_ the original geometries, grouping and combinations included. Frankly, at this point your question seems very unclear to me as to what it is exactly you are looking for. Markup is not the same as the geometry stream syntax, and if you want a single geometry stream that represents the post-combined/grouped geometries, you're going to have to write that yourself. It's not in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just flatten the geometry. Note however that this returns a polygon-representation of your geometry.

`union.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().ToString()`

To maintain the original curves, there seem to be many built-in variations for for this and I will leave them here for future readers.

```
PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(combined).ToString()
PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(union).ToString()
Geometry.Combine(hBar, vBar, GeometryCombineMode.Union, null).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing the point but getting the paths back is quite simple...

```
foreach(var child in combined.Children)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" child of combined = {child.ToString()}");
}
Console.WriteLine($" union.Geometry1 = {union.Geometry1}");
Console.WriteLine($" union.Geometry2 = {union.Geometry2}");
```

Which produces...

```
child of combined = F1M10,20L40,20 40,30 10,30z
child of combined = F1M20,10L30,10 30,40 20,40z
union.Geometry1 = F1M10,20L40,20 40,30 10,30z
union.Geometry2 = F1M20,10L30,10 30,40 20,40z
```

Comment: I’m not looking for the constituent parts. I’m looking for the representation of the *resulting* geometry. Hope that makes more sense.